# Random number list with only two numbers

Tags: r, random

This is really simple, but I keep getting stuck! I am trying to create a list in R of 1000 zeros with the number 1.5 added 20 times at random intervals, to look like:

```
0.000
0.000
1.500
0.000
1.500
0.000
0.000
```

But am stuck on how to keep it as just the two numbers? I have been using the seq command but can't get the arguments right...

Comment: Your desired output is unclear. How many total zeroes will there be in the end? 1000 or 980?

Comment: another option would be to create what you want first `rep(c(0, 1.5), c(980, 20))` and then randomize the order of that `rep(c(0, 1.5), c(980, 20))[sample(1000)]`

Answer (score 5):

Sample the indices:

```
x <- numeric(1000) #adjust to 1020 if you really need 1000 zeros in the result
x[sample(length(x), 20)] <- 1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sample(c(double(1000L),rep(1.5,20L)));
```

---

In my above solution I assumed you meant "inserted" when you said "added", thus giving a vector with length 1020. If you meant "added" (as in addition against the zero) you can use this:

```
sample(c(double(980L),rep(1.5,20L)));
```

Comment: Hmm, I think the OP meant "inserted" instead of "added", i.e. 1000 zeroes with 20 1.5s inserted at random intervals, giving a total length of 1020.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
x <- rep(0, 1000)
positions <- round(runif(20, 1, 1000))
x[positions] <- 1.5
```

First row generates a vector of zeros and then, twenty random positions are overwritten with 1.5.

Comment: This can result in less than 20 assigned values, it's basically sampling with replacement.